# why this in code 'IResult<H>'

Tags: c#, generics, interface

While learning a program I got stuck on this code .. What is the H inside'<>

```
public interface IResult<H>
    {
        bool IsSuccess { get; set; }
        string Message { get; set; }
        H Data { get; set; }
    }
public interface Employee {
    int ID { get; set; }
    string Sex { get; set; }
    string Name { get; set; }

     IResult Save();
}
```

It'd very helpful if someone can explain Iresult and H Data property

Comment: It's called "Generics". Google for "C# generics".

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a programming concept that is easy findable in the documentation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a [Generic Type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/512aeb7t.aspx), meaning you can substitute any type in it's place and have a type-safe class.  For example:

```
// it's an interface, you can't actually do this (of course).  If it was a 
// normal class, then no problem.  This is just for demonstration
IResult<string> x = new IResult<string>();
x.Data = "My String";
```

It is probably used with a user defined class, such as something from the database, like this (just a guess, can't see the other code):

```
var result = myEmployeeRecord.Save();  // result is of type IResult<Employee>

if (result.IsSuccess) { 
    Display(result.Message);
} else {
    Display("Error: " + result.Data.Name + " could not be saved");
    // result.Data is of type "Employee"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`IResult<H>` is a [generic interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kwtft8ak%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), it allows you to pass in a type at compile-type where `H` is the type. You can use it like this:

```
IResult<Employee> Save();
```

This means the type will be `Emloyee`. As you see the interface contains a property:

```
H Data { get; set; }
```

`H` will become the type you specified above, so `Employee` in this case.